# Jacoco is adding a $jacocoInit method in my interface when running unit tests

Tags: java, jacoco

I am getting a unnecessary method $jacocoInit when adding the defaut method in interface. My interface looks like this:

```
@Value.Immutable
public interface Customer {


    Optional<@NotBlank String> name();

    default Object getObject(final String abc) {
        return null
    }

    default void getObject() {

    }
}
```

When I am doing

```
for (Method method : Customer.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    System.out.println(method.getName());
}
```

then, I am getting

```
name
getObject
$jacocoInit
```

If I remove the default method from it, then it does not $jacocInit method. I am not sure why it is happening? Can someone please help in this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [JaCoCo FAQ](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/faq.html):

> To collect execution data JaCoCo instruments the classes under test which adds two members to the classes: A private static field `$jacocoData` and a private static method `$jacocoInit()`. Both members are marked as synthetic.
>
> Please change your code to ignore synthetic members. This is a good practice anyways as also the Java compiler creates synthetic members in certain situation.

[Method `isSynthetic` of class `java.lang.reflect.Method`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#isSynthetic())

> Returns true if this executable is a synthetic construct; returns false otherwise.

So to ignore synthetic members:

```
for (Method method : Customer.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    if (method.isSynthetic()) {
        continue;
    }
    System.out.println(method.getName());
}
```

---

And here is one of many examples where Java compiler creates synthetic method:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

class Example {

    interface I {
        Runnable r = () -> {}; // lambda

        void m();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Method method : I.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            System.out.println("name: " + method.getName());
            System.out.println("isSynthetic: " + method.isSynthetic());
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Using JDK `1.8.0_152` execution of

```
javac Example.java
java Example
```

produces

```
name: m
isSynthetic: false

name: lambda$static$0
isSynthetic: true
```

And here is what [Java Virtual Machine Specification states about synthetic members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se13/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.8):

> A class member that does not appear in the source code must be marked using a Synthetic attribute, [...]

You can read more about JaCoCo implementation in [its documentation](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/) and in [presentations done by JaCoCo team](https://www.jacoco.org/research/index.html), which also include some other examples of synthetic constructions.